# How does one use TrafficStats.incrementOperationCount()?

Tags: android

The documentation for  [`TrafficStats.incrementOperationCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#incrementOperationCount%28int,%20int%29) says:

> Increment count of network operations performed under the given
>   accounting tag. This can be used to derive bytes-per-operation.

I want to find the total number of bytes transferred during a particular network operation. Since this API claims to help in deriving bytes-per-operation, can someone help me understand how to use it?

Comment: Please see my main problem as stated in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10179177/165674).

Answer (score 1):

[CountingInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html) [CountingOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/CountingOutputStream.html)
I am not sure this will help you or not, but it do helpful me to get number of bytes sent and received in particular stream.

you can mold the actual use of it, create such logic that addition(number to byte sent and received) is the total number of bytes transferred during a particular network operation

Comment: Interesting, but it won't help due to the reasons mentioned in [this new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10179177/165674).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really want to do, but maybe this example can help: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/create-a-network-monitor-using-androids-trafficstats-class/774

Another possible way to do it would be to use a sniffer like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=vadim.ofer.sniffer&hl=en